# implicit instantiation of undefined template errors from fstream

Tags: c++, xcode, fstream

Consider the following MWE

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main () {
   char data[100];

   // open a file in write mode.
   ofstream outfile;
   outfile.open("/Users/Dropbox/afile.dat");

   cout << "Writing to the file" << endl;
   cout << "Enter your name: ";
   cin.getline(data, 100);

   // write inputted data into the file.
   outfile << data << endl;

   outfile.close();

   return 0;
}
```

This is giving me a lot of "Implicit instantiation of undefined template" errors on the Xcode on my mac. In fact, even if I remove the contents of the main function, it still gives the following error inside fstream due to `#include<fstream>`.

```
Return type of out-of-line definition of 'std::__1::basic_filebuf::setbuf' differs from that in the declaration
```

My friend ran the same on his Xcode and it works. Is the fstream library corrupted? Can you tell how to resolve this?

Comment: What compiler flags are being used? Perhaps the standard library distributed with one version of the compiler is being used with a different version of the compiler?

Comment: I simply built a new project on Xcode with the above main.cpp included in the compile sources. Rest all settings are default and no compiler flags were added. Note that fstream worked well before. Things changed after I was trying to change the data file names dynamically. I am not sure if that corrupted some files but after that, fstream errors are coming on newly created independent projects.

Comment: I suppose uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode might be a good next troubleshooting step. Make sure that this also uninstalls and reinstalls the compiler and standard library.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `ofstream outfile; outfile.open("/Users/Dropbox/afile.dat");` to `ofstream  And, finally, you don't need the extraoutfile("/Users/Dropbox/afile.dat");`. Also, you don't need to call `outfile.close()`. The destructor will do that. And, finally, this code doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks. Any advice on dynamic file names using ofstream? It seems messing that up may have caused these issues.

Comment: @cdhowie, reinstalling Xcode worked. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "dynamic file names". `std::ofstream` wants the name of a file. That can be a string literal (`"abcd.txt"`), a pointer to `char` (const char *fname = "abcd.txt";), or an `std::string`. The form of the file name shouldn't be a problem. It's quite common to pass the name of a file to a function that opens the file and does something with it. The file name typically comes in as a `const char*` or `const std::string&`.